# How to find the solution to this ODE in terms of Bessel Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I want to obtain a solution for the ODE:

$$x^2 y''+xy'+(16x^2-\alpha^2)y=0$$

and I can see that it looks similar to a Bessel Equation:

$$x^2 y'' +xy'+(x^2-n^2)y=0$$

but I'm not sure how to "transform it"...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut you mean let $u = 4x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kenny pointed out in his comment for the equation
$$x^2 y''+xy'+(\beta^2x^2-\alpha^2)y=0$$
Simply substitute $z=\beta x$ the equation becomes a Bessel equation
$$z^2 y''+zy'+(z^2-\alpha^2)y=0$$
With solution
$$y(z)=C_1J_{\alpha}(z)+C_2Y_{\alpha}(z)$$

$$ \implies y(x)=C_1J_{\alpha}(\beta x)+C_2Y_{\alpha}(\beta x)$$